How to use Google App Script to send a PDF file using POST request
I want to use Google Apps Script with a Google Doc to send a PDF file uploaded to Google Drive to an API that I am creating. The API summarizes some of the contents of the text of the PDF file and returns an HTML file containing the summary.
The API uses fast API and is working well with Swagger UI, but not when called from Google Apps Script. Here is the GAS code:
function process_PDF_file() {

  const PDF_fileId = "###"; // This is the file ID of the PDF uploaded to Google Drive 
                            //  that will be sent to the API

  var url = "###"; This is the url of the API
  const payload = {file: DriveApp.getFileById(PDF_fileId).getBlob() };
  let config = { muteHttpExceptions: true, payload };
  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, config);
  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  Logger.log(data);
}

Here are routes of the API, which is written in Python:
    @app.get("/")
    async def root():
        return {"message": "Hello Summary Creator"}


    @app.post("/file")
    async def endpoint(uploaded_file: bytes = File()):
    
        content = uploaded_file
        filename = "temp.pdf"
        with open(filename, "wb") as f:
            f.write(content)
        main_routine()
        return {"Summary": f"{summary_download}"}


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)

Running the GAS code results in the following entry in the Execution log:

10:56:22 AM    Info {detail=[{type=missing, url=https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.9/v/missing, input=null, loc=[body, uploaded_file], msg=Field required}]}

A similar question was asked by user3347814 on Oct. 20, 2023 at 14:03: How to use Google App Script to send a file using POST request
The previous question, however, concerned multipart/form-data, which might not apply to my situation. In any event, I tried using using some techniques for handling multipart/form-data, including the GAS library supplied by Tanaike, who gave the accepted answer to the previous question, but I still received similar error messages when running the GAS code.
Any suggestions for fixing the problems would be appreciated.

First, about In any event, I tried using using some techniques for handling multipart/form-data, including the GAS library supplied by Tanaike, who gave the accepted answer to the previous question, but I still received similar error messages when running the GAS code., I deeply apologize that my script was not useful for your situation. I would like to correctly understand your situation.


In your situation, when you request @app.get("/") by Google Apps Script, what result will you obtain? 2. If you request @app.post("/file") with a curl command using the public URL, what result will you obtain by what curl command?


No apologies needed. For one thing, the situation is different, involving a PDF file, which can be difficult to work with and may require special handling. Also, my problem could easily have nothing to do with your script. To answer your questions:

To answer your questions: (1) "Hello Summary Creator" is the data returned from a request to @app.get("/") by Google Apps Script; (2) I receive the following error message when I request @app.post("/file") with a curl command using the public URL: {"detail":[{"type":"missing","loc":["body","uploaded_file"],"msg":"Field required","input":null,"url":"https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.9/v/missing"}]}.

Thank you for replying. From (1) "Hello Summary Creator" is the data returned from a request to @app.get("/") by Google Apps Script;, I could confirm that your public URL can be accessed from Google side. From (2) I receive the following error message when I request @app.post("/file") with a curl command using the public URL, although I'm not sure about your tested curl command, when you test it in the same location with the server, what result did you obtain? And, can you provide your tested curl command?

Thank you for your response.
Here is my tested curl command: curl -H "Content-Type: application/pdf" -X POST -d "file=@C:\Users\mdbro\Desktop\FastAPI Tutorial\temp_brief.pdf" https://toa-creator7-710668889746.us-west1.run.app/file
Here is the result I obtained: {"detail":[{"type":"missing","loc":["body","uploaded_file"],"msg":"Field required","input":null,"url":"https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.9/v/missing"}]}
I issued the curl command from a terminal in VS Code. If you wanted something else, please let me know and provide more details about how to perform the specific type of curl testing.

Thank you for replying. In your curl command, the URL https://toa-creator7-710668889746.us-west1.run.app/file was tested with the same location as the server. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, how about curl -F "file=@C:\Users\mdbro\Desktop\FastAPI Tutorial\temp_brief.pdf" toa-creator7-710668889746.us-west1.run.app/file? Because in the case of -d "file=, the filename is sent as form data. First, I would like to confirm whether the POST method can be used on the same server.

Thank you for your suggestion. When I try your curl command, however, I get no response for some reason. My curl command from yesterday gives the same response as before. I believe your understanding about the testing of the curl commands is correct. The public URL is associated the Google server hosting the public API and can be accessed independently of my computer. I am issuing the curl commands on my PC with Windows 10 using a terminal provided by VS Code. I very much appreciate all your help. I am going to try modifying the API code to see if that might fix the problems. Thank you again!

Thank you for replying. About When I try your curl command, however, I get no response for some reason., I would like to recommend that first, you know the specification of your server. About My curl command from yesterday gives the same response as before., at least, your provided curl command doesn't upload the file content. Please be careful about this. When you can request your server from both the local and the public with the curl command, I think that it can be converted to Google Apps Script.

Thank you, @Tanaike, for your recommendations!
